# c++ different basics types during converting variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variables

c++ problem different basics types during converting variables
Yes, stupid problem, but I'm newbie in c++ and IDK what's the problem.

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float a = 54;
cout << a;
double(a);
cout << a;
return 0;
}
```

and this errors:

- error **C2371**: 'a' : redefinition; different basic types line 7
- error **C2088**: '<<' : illegal for class line 8

why it wrote: *different basics types*, when I converting only float to double? and what does it mean second error? what **class line**?

and I have this question too: Can I convert 2 variables with different basic types f.e. int to string? and is it same as converting f.e. double to float or different?

[Here is print screen during debugging project in VC++ 2010](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/1633/d4c4e9dd56b74b0b8c40490.png)

Comment: [Get yourself a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Unrelated: The full error messages for Visual Studio are in the "output" window, not the "error" window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already declared 'a' as a `float`, and the compiler thinks you're trying to redeclare it as a `double`.  Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float a = 54;
    cout << a;
    double b(a);
    cout << b;
    return 0;
}
```

As far as your second question goes:

> Can I convert 2 variables with different basic types f.e. int to
>   string? and is it same as converting f.e. double to float or
>   different?

The answer is that you cannot convert them implicitly or even directly (and have them preserve their meaning, that is), but you can certainly use facilities such as `std::stringstream`, etc. to do the conversion for you.  Conversion from `float` to `double`, on the other hand, is an implicit conversion that the compiler will do for you.

Comment: gah, I just remembered on the easier solution. How I can check if user written input **int** type?

Comment: @mwingdahl: I don't think we should recommend `sprintf` for conversion in C++, use `std::stringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: @Cehppel: That is a completely different question, and requires it's own page.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Good point!  My C roots are showing, apparently!  :)  Edited.

Comment: ok, I will create new topic, if my try fails. thanks for all advices

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049549/c-number-input-validation and it's ok!