# Handling exceptions in c++ with typeid

Tags: c++, error-handling, typeid

I am improve my abilities at handling error exceptions in c++ and I ran into a problem with a simple test.

**Problem**: I have made a function called division which gets two numbers from the user. If the the denominator is 0 then an exception should be throw and handled. Also, if the user enters a const char * an exception should be thrown.

**Approach**: I originally didn't even worry about const char *, but now I am really annoyed that I can't figure out why my condition statements aren't being executed. I could just leave it, but I want to know what is going on.

**Code**: This is a really simple example so I just attached my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename T2>
double division(T num1, T2 num2)
{
   if (num2 == 0)
   {
      throw num2;
   }
   return (double) num1 / num2;
}  

int main()
{

   double num1 = 0.0;
   double num2 = 0.0;

   try
   {
      cout << "Enter a number that you would like to divide : " << endl;
      cin >> num1;

      if (typeid(num1).name() == "const char *" )
      {
         cout << "I ran" << endl;
         throw string("You must enter a number");
      }

      cout << "Enter the number that you would like to divide  the first 
      number by : " << endl;
      cin >> num2;

      if (typeid(num2).name() == "const char *" )
      {
         throw string("You must enter a number");
      }

      cout << "Result " << division(num1, num2) << endl;
   }
   catch (string & p)
   {
      cout << "String error message : " << p << endl;
   }
   catch (double e)
   {
      cout << "You cannot divide by " << e << " please try again " << endl;
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea. Counts for a serious design flaw. Consider using templates.

Comment: `double num1 = 0.0;` says that `num1` is always a `double` so the `typeid` test will never work. What you *can* test is the result of `cin >> num1` to see if it did read anything, [perhaps like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4049588/597607)

Comment: `typeid(num1).name()` : _"Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string..."_ why do you expect it be: `"const char *"` ?  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name

Comment: Re: " if the user enters a const char *" -- the user cannot enter a `const char*`. That's a type that may or may not be used in your code. Users enter **text**, and the problem you're talking about is what to do if the text that the user enters does not represent a valid value of type `double`. It's important to keep that in mind: users enter **text** and your program **interprets** that text.

Comment: If `const char*` is bad then better handle it at compile time, no?

Comment: If you want to input anything that is **not** a number you can't use numeric variables like `double`. Maybe use a `std::string` first then try to convert it to a `double`?

Comment: Don’t throw arbitrary types. Throw something derived from std::exception. You may choose std::runtime_error as your base. It implements the handling of the error message.

Comment: While we're at it, better get rid of `#include "stdafx.h"` and `using namespace std`.

Comment: All of these crazy solutions to a simple problem. I figured out that if I assigned a char * to my double variable num1 then num1 is zero. So,  I can just use num1 and num2 to check if a char * was entered. Anyways I am happy.